# ggplot labels\legend not encoded in UTF-8 (RTL language) when R markdown is rendered as HTML

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, r-markdown, hebrew

I'm trying to render an R markdown report as an HTML file. My .Rmd includes ggplot figures with Hebrew (RTL language) labels, axes titles and legends. When I render the report as HTML, the resulting file displays the Hebrew text unencoded (i.e. not as UTF-8 as needed) and unreadable.

The ggplot figures read Hebrew text from both a tibble (Hebrew factors in the data, encoded as UTF-8) and ggplot functions like `ylab()`.

Any thoughts on how to encode Hebrew text within ggplot, in an HTML R-markdown?

Thanks,
Yoav

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I had the same issue with Norwegian characters. If you are on Windows, try file encoding  "windows-1252". That did the trick for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip! Are u referring to the encoding argument in rmarkdown::render()?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I totally missed your comment! Yes, as `render("test.html",encoding="windows-1252")`. Hopefully it will work! Otherwise add a reproducible example so we can try to replicate your issue.